# How to cin data to store in a struct defined in another header file?

Tags: visual-c++

I am working on my homework and am stuck at this place. It would he helpful if someone could help me with this. I am using Visual C++.

This is a header file with a class.

```
#ifndef CALLER_H
#define CALLER_H

#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include "nodeData.h"

using namespace std;

class Caller {
    private:
        int phone_number;
        void setPhoneNumber(){
            int min = 300000;
            int max = 800000;
            phone_number = min + rand()%(max-min+1);
        }

    string callers_name;
    string message;
};

#endif
```

I am trying to store string of name and message into the above header file but I am getting error. I have searched on google and this was one possible solution:  "cin >> Caller.callers_name;" but still getting error. It is same for "cin >> Caller.message;".

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

QueueList L;
Caller * caller = NULL;
int choice;


const int columnSize = 3;
string columnNames[columnSize];

cout <<"\n\t\tANZ Call Center Simulation\n";
cout <<"\n\tPress 1 to make a call by a caller.\n";
cout <<"\tPress 2 to receive a call by a consultant.\n";
cout <<"\tPress 3 to print all callers.\n\tChoice: ";
cin >>choice;

if (choice == 1){
    cout <<"\n\tPlease leave your name and message.\n";
    cout <<"\tEnter Name: ";
    cin >> Caller.callers_name;
    cout <<"\n\tMessage: ";
    cin >> Caller.message;
}else if (choice == 2){

}

..............

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried to fix your code, but I think the spacing is off and/or your missing braces.

Comment: Also, what is the error message, and what have you tried to fix it?

Comment: Error Messages are:

: warning C4832: token '.' is illegal after UDT 'Caller'
: see declaration of 'Caller'
: error C2275: 'Caller' : illegal use of this type as an expression
: see declaration of 'Caller'
error C2228: left of '.callers_name' must have class/struct/union
: warning C4832: token '.' is illegal after UDT 'Caller'

and some more list of errors

Comment: Note that Class Caller is in a different header file and int _tmain........ is a different file. It is a project.